# Toggle position fixed depending on scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-position

I have the following code which fixes the position of a menu at the point that it is going to scroll off the top of the page.

```
$(function () {
    var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;
    if (!msie6) {
    var top = $('.menu').offset().top - parseFloat($('.menu').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y >= top) {
    $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
    $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
    });
    }
});
```

css

```
.container {
    width:400px; 
    margin:auto;
}

.header {
    background-color:#096; 
    height:150px;
}

.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:50px;
}

.bodyContainer {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.menu {
    float:right; 
    width:150px; 
    height:250px; 
    background-color:#F00;
}

.bodyCopy {
    float:left; 
    width:250px; 
    height:1000px;
}

.footer {
    background-color:#096; 
    height:250px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">

<div class="header">
    <p>Test Header</p>
</div>

<div class="bodyContainer">

    <div class="menu">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>

    <div class="bodyCopy">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="footer">
    <p>Test Footer</p>
</div>
```

What I now want to do is make it start scrolling again when the user reaches the bottom of the page (so that it does not cover the footer in the page).

[jsfiddle here...](http://jsfiddle.net/CV3UA/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var top = $('.menu').offset().top - parseFloat($('.menu').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
var _height = $('.menu').height();
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    var z = $('.footer').offset().top;
    if (y >= top && (y+_height) < z) {
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/CV3UA/1/

If you want the menu to simply stay where it is when it reaches the footer you'll need to add more logic to append it into the DOM:

```
var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;
if (!msie6) {
    var top = $('.menu').offset().top - parseFloat($('.menu').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    var _height = $('.menu').height();
    var _original_top = $('.menu').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        var z = $('.footer').offset().top;
        if (y >= top && (y + _height) < z) {
            $('.menu').insertBefore($('.bodyCopy')).removeClass('stuck-bottom').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            if ((y + _height) >= z) {
                $('#menu').insertBefore($('.footer')).removeClass('fixed').addClass('stuck-bottom');
            }
            else $('.menu').insertBefore($('.bodyCopy')).removeClass('stuck-bottom').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
}
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this. Play around :)
http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/CV3UA/2/

Comment: I like that... Is there a way to make it start to scroll again though rather than jumping back to it's original position somewhere way off the top of the screen?? Thanks

Comment: Just need to edit line 12 above to stop a slight flicker... thanks - if ((y + _height) >= z) {

Answer (score 7):

Here is new a approach with css3.

use `position:sticky` to follows the scroll.

Here is the article explained.

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit

and old way of doing this [demo](http://jsbin.com/omanut/2)

with [sticky position demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html)

Comment: yeah, but chrome doesn't support it yet :(