# Sidebar which scrolls with the main content

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, positioning

How to implement a sidebar, which is positioned somewhere at the page and when user scrolls page down, it changes positioning and scrolls with the main content, always remaining visible?

Here is an [example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html)  (scroll down, please)

---

Oh dear! I just had to specify the following style (which wasn't too obvious for me):

```
.affix {
    position: fixed;
}
```

And, of course, to add jQuery:

```
$('.leftnav').affix();
```

*Huge thanks to everyone, who tried to help me!*

Comment: @epascarello Khm, yes, probably... But firstly it positioned `N` px from the top, and then it changes position to `M` px from the top. Or `fixed position` depends only on parent element?

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984645/toggle-position-fixed-depending-on-scroll-position. The example you gave does not work on safari on iPad.

Comment: @Edward Ruchevits: See my answer below: Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the source for the page you've linked to. The solution involves changing to position fixed upon user scroll down just enough to top edge of menu reach top edge of the screen (that's done by listening to `scroll` events). Initialy (when page is served) the menu doesn't have position fixed.

Edit:
Or better yet... here's script that will do just that http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try `position: fixed`:

> http://jsfiddle.net/FlameTrap/mfyAc/

** **EDIT** **

Try this:

> http://jsfiddle.net/FlameTrap/Wqb3g/1/

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to listen to every scroll event, and change the position of the element as it scrolls, either changing to `fixed` after a threshold, or continuously updating:

```
var newPos = Math.max( startPosition, scrollTop + scrollOffset)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KF29z/)

**JS CODE:**

```
        var ns = (navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape") != -1);
        var d = document;
        function JSFX_FloatDiv(id, sx, sy)
        {
            var el=d.getElementById?d.getElementById(id):d.all?d.all[id]:d.layers[id];
            var px = document.layers ? "" : "px";
            window[id + "_obj"] = el;
            if(d.layers)el.style=el;
            el.cx = el.sx = sx;el.cy = el.sy = sy;
            el.sP=function(x,y){this.style.left=x+px;this.style.top=y+px;};
        
            el.floatIt=function()
            {
                var pX, pY;
                pX = (this.sx >= 0) ? 0 : ns ? innerWidth : 
                document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth ? 
                document.documentElement.clientWidth : document.body.clientWidth;
                pY = ns ? pageYOffset : document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop ? 
                document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;
                if(this.sy<0) 
                pY += ns ? innerHeight : document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight ? 
                document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight;
                this.cx += (pX + this.sx - this.cx)/8;this.cy += (pY + this.sy - this.cy)/8;
                this.sP(this.cx, this.cy);
                setTimeout(this.id + "_obj.floatIt()", 40);
            }
            return el;
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="divTopLeft" style="position:absolute">
        <script>JSFX_FloatDiv("divTopLeft", 10,30).floatIt();</script>
        <ul>
            <li id="img1">Image 1</li>
            <li id="img2">Image 2</li>
            <li id="img3">Image 3</li>
            <li id="img4">Image 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #main {
        width: 1280px;
        height:720px;
        background: url(http://www.designworks.com.pk/example/background/images/1.jpg) left top no-repeat;
        margin: 0;
        position:relative;
        z-index:2;
    }
    ul { margin:20px; display:inline-block; }
    ul li { cursor:pointer; list-style-type: none; color: #fff; background:#000; border:1px solid #fff; font-size:16px; font-weight: bold; padding: 5px; margin:2px 0 0 0;  }
    ul li#img1 { background:#F90; }
```