# DIV is fixed after a specific point

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-position

My website looks like this:
http://im.bilderkiste.org/1137050965009/size.jpg

The first block is an image with content in it and the second block (black) is the navigation. I want the following thing:
When you scroll down the page, the second block scrolls normaly to the top, when the second block is on top - it should change the css property to (position: fixed;).

But when you scroll to the top, the second block changes to the position in which it was at the beginning.

Like on this page: http://focuslabllc.com/expressionengine (the second navigation)

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984645/toggle-position-fixed-depending-on-scroll-position

Comment: please close this question or answer it yourself for it to be considered answered